# set a text output colour

Tags: swift, xcode6

I have a textfield that has a sum attached to the output
just wondering how do I write a line that has the effect of:

If the final figure is less then zero the text colour is red
and if the output is positive figure text is another colour.

```
txtsum.textColor = UIColor (red: 255.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

This works to set the colour as red.

Just don’t know how to write a statement( if thats what I need) guessing its if and else statement

This my output line

```
txtsum!.text  = NSString(format: "%.2f", sum1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed a simple if statement. Run this every time you change the text of the text field:

```
if sum1 < 0 {
    txtsum.textColor = UIColor(red: 255.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
else {
    txtsum.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Comment: knew it was something as simple as this, total newbie here. Thank you for taking the time to answer.